# C++ or C library for creating iso images

Tags: library, c++, c, iso

I am currently searching a pure C or C++ library for creating hybrid ISO images. I have found: [Cdlib](http://libcdrom.sourceforge.net/index.html) - far too outdated, and [GNU libcdio](http://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/) - I cannot use GPL code in my software.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially, a question should point out all requirements; just naming "other examples" by link is insufficient as well (see: [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185)).